# Spring boot threads are waiting org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:invokeHandlerMethod:827

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

We have developed set of APIs using spring boot. When performance test was run and hitting more than 5000 calls/minute, avg response time started increasing. When we investigated with the help of AppDynamics, more than 2% transactions are having slow response time (more than 1.5 seconds). But the CPU usage is still under 20%.

And all of them are waiting exactly at the same location i. e `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:invokeHandlerMethod:827.`

Below is the complete call graph.

```
HTTPServlet:service:742 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
HTTPServlet:service:661 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
Servlet - dispatcherServlet:doService:897 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
Servlet - dispatcherServlet:doDispatch:963 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
Web Service - org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:handleInternal:738 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
Web Service - org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:invokeHandlerMethod:827 (method time = 0 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport:parkNanos:215 (method time = 1800 ms, total time = 1800 ms)
```

What is the root cause for threads handing at this location? Are there any SpringBooot properties to be updated to eliminate this?

Following is the source code of RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:invokeHandlerMethod and it hangs at invocableMethod.invokeAndHandle(webRequest, mavContainer);

protected ModelAndView invokeHandlerMethod(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) throws Exception {

```
    ServletWebRequest webRequest = new ServletWebRequest(request, response);
    try {
        WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory = getDataBinderFactory(handlerMethod);
        ModelFactory modelFactory = getModelFactory(handlerMethod, binderFactory);

        ServletInvocableHandlerMethod invocableMethod = createInvocableHandlerMethod(handlerMethod);
        invocableMethod.setHandlerMethodArgumentResolvers(this.argumentResolvers);
        invocableMethod.setHandlerMethodReturnValueHandlers(this.returnValueHandlers);
        invocableMethod.setDataBinderFactory(binderFactory);
        invocableMethod.setParameterNameDiscoverer(this.parameterNameDiscoverer);

        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer = new ModelAndViewContainer();
        mavContainer.addAllAttributes(RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request));
        modelFactory.initModel(webRequest, mavContainer, invocableMethod);
        mavContainer.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(this.ignoreDefaultModelOnRedirect);

        AsyncWebRequest asyncWebRequest = WebAsyncUtils.createAsyncWebRequest(request, response);
        asyncWebRequest.setTimeout(this.asyncRequestTimeout);

        WebAsyncManager asyncManager = WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(request);
        asyncManager.setTaskExecutor(this.taskExecutor);
        asyncManager.setAsyncWebRequest(asyncWebRequest);
        asyncManager.registerCallableInterceptors(this.callableInterceptors);
        asyncManager.registerDeferredResultInterceptors(this.deferredResultInterceptors);

        if (asyncManager.hasConcurrentResult()) {
            Object result = asyncManager.getConcurrentResult();
            mavContainer = (ModelAndViewContainer) asyncManager.getConcurrentResultContext()[0];
            asyncManager.clearConcurrentResult();
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("Found concurrent result value [" + result + "]");
            }
            invocableMethod = invocableMethod.wrapConcurrentResult(result);
        }

        invocableMethod.invokeAndHandle(webRequest, mavContainer);
        if (asyncManager.isConcurrentHandlingStarted()) {
            return null;
        }

        return getModelAndView(mavContainer, modelFactory, webRequest);
    }
    finally {
        webRequest.requestCompleted();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you find this out? We just encountered the exact same issue at the exact same method on the exact same line discovered by using appdynamics. In our case basically 99% of our requests are getting stuck and our app essentially grinds to a halt.

Comment: any updates on this one?

Comment: @I.Domshchikov sorry for being so late.we couldnt find a fix for this.

Comment: @user997811, any update on resolution or how did you mitigate?
similar issue i'm facing too .

Comment: @Abhinavmanthri Sorry to say that we could not solve this issue.

Comment: @AlmaAlma, found any solution for your case? it will be helpful if you could share

Comment: @Abhinavmanthri Nope. Sorry but I could not find any solution and I gave up eventually. I just simply wrote it off as a poor way impementing synchronization in the Spring Boot framework if I remember correctly